# DbContext Update is not working but Get is working. Why?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

I implemented Repository and UnitOfWork pattern in my Core Layer:

```
public class Repository<TEntity, TContext> : UnitOfWork, IRepository<TEntity>
 where TEntity : class, new()
 where TContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TContext _context;

    public Repository(TContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _context = dbContext;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddAsync(TEntity model)
    {
        await _context.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(model);
        return true;
    }

    public List<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().ToList();
    }

    public bool Remove(TEntity model)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(model);
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public bool Update(TEntity model)
    {
        _context.Set<TEntity>().Update(model);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;
    private readonly IDbContextTransaction _transaction;

    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        _transaction = _context.Database.CurrentTransaction ?? _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public async Task<bool> Commit(bool state = true)
    {
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            if (state)
                _transaction.Commit();
            else
                _transaction.Rollback();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            _transaction.Rollback();
            throw; // Rethrow the exception after rolling back the transaction
        }
        finally
        {
            Dispose();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual async void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            await _context.DisposeAsync();
            _transaction.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

So ı am using this class in my DataAccess and BusinessLayer and finally in my MVC Controller like layered structure. I can get values when ı call Get() method. But ı tried to change one value via Update() method did not work. Despite ı call SaveAsync() method.

I am sharing my DataAccess and Business Layer under.

DataAccess:

```
public class ResponsibleDal : Repository<Responsible, TaskTracingDbContext>, IResponsibleDal
{
    public ResponsibleDal(TaskTracingDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {

    }
}
```

DataAccess Factory:

```
public class MainDal : IMainDal
{
    private readonly Lazy<IResponsibleDal> _responsibleDalLazy;

    public MainDal(IResponsibleDal responsibleDalLazy)
    {
        _responsibleDalLazy = new Lazy<IResponsibleDal>(() => responsibleDalLazy);
    }

    public IResponsibleDal ResponsibleDal => _responsibleDalLazy.Value;
}
```

Business:

```
public class ResponsibleBus : IResponsibleBus
{
    private readonly IMainDal _mainDal;

    public ResponsibleBus(IMainDal mainDal)
    {
        _mainDal = mainDal;
    }

    public async Task<bool> AddAsync(Responsible model)
    {
        return await _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.AddAsync(model);
    }

    public List<Responsible> Get()
    {
        return _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.Get();
    }

    public bool Remove(Responsible model)
    {
        return _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.Remove(model);
    }

    public Task<int> SaveAsync()
    {
        return _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.SaveAsync();
    }

    public Responsible? GetById(int id)
    {
        return _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.Get().Find(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public Responsible? GetByIdentityNumber(string? identityNumber)
    {
        if (identityNumber is null)
            return null;
        return _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.Get().Find(x => x.IdentityNumber == identityNumber);
    }
    public bool Update(Responsible model)
    {
        return _mainDal.ResponsibleDal.Update(model);
    }
}
```

Business Factory:

```
public class MainBus : IMainBus
{
    private readonly Lazy<IResponsibleBus> _responsibleBusLazy;

    public MainBus(IResponsibleBus responsibleBusLazy)
    {
        _responsibleBusLazy = new Lazy<IResponsibleBus>(() => responsibleBusLazy);
    }

    public IResponsibleBus ResponsibleBus => _responsibleBusLazy.Value;
}
```

Finally in my Controller:

```
var entity = _mainBus.ResponsibleBus.GetByIdentityNumber(model.UserName);

if (entity is not null)
{
    entity.ThemeSettings = model.Theme;
    _mainBus.ResponsibleBus.Update(entity);
    await _mainBus.ResponsibleBus.SaveAsync();

    HttpContext.Session.SetString("Theme", model.Theme.ToString());
}
else
{
    TempData["Error"] = "Kullanıcı veritabanında bulunamadı";
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), model);
}
```

Also I scoped like this in Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<TaskTracingDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IResponsibleDal, ResponsibleDal>();
builder.Services.AddTransient(provider => new Lazy<IResponsibleDal>(provider.GetRequiredService<IResponsibleDal>()));

builder.Services.AddTransient<IResponsibleBus, ResponsibleBus>();
builder.Services.AddTransient(provider => new Lazy<IResponsibleBus>(provider.GetRequiredService<IResponsibleBus>()));


builder.Services.AddTransient<IMainDal, MainDal>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMainBus, MainBus>();
```

Can you explain to me the detail I don't know?

Comment: I forgat to say, ı added add-migration to create my database And ı change my some entities data type and again ı added migration and updated db

Comment: Also add not working too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos help me master ı am still junior.

Comment: *"Update is not working"* - did you get an error or it just silently does nothing?

Comment: @BagusTesa No error but not save in database. Sliently

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Because of the `SaveAsync()` method in Repository class. I had to call `Commit()` method under the `UnitOfWork` class. `Commit()` method Saving Changes.

```
public async Task<bool> SaveAsync()
{
    return await Commit();
}
```

Comment: If anyone explain more detailed. I thank you.

Comment: DbContext is already an implementation of the Repository and UnitOfWork pattern.  There should be no need to repeat, unless you want to prepare your code to have EF exchanged in the future for something else.